# Java passing a string array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm pretty new to Java and I'm doing some things for practice. I'm just messing with simple IO stuff right now, reading from a file and then printing to an output. I also played with removing commas from the input and got that part working. My problem is when I try to print the values in my array into a new file. Is the fact that my array is created inside the while loop for the BufferedReader? How can I get the values in the array `values` to be seen by the BufferedWriter? I'm also curious how I would go about reversing the order of the array when printing to the output file? Thanks for any help guys, I've searched but haven't been able to come across anything this specific.

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myImport.txt"));
        String line = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            System.out.println("Your file has been evaluated, here are the contents:");
            for (String str : values) {
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        }
        br.close();

        try {

            File file = new File("myOutput.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(values);
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                fw.write(values[i] + "\n");
            }
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use bw.write(values[i] + "\n"); Be sure to close the FileWriter as well when you're done. And to do in reverse order, just reverse the direction of your for loop: `for (int i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {}`

Comment: It's hard to tell with the bad indentation, but it looks like `values` is within the scope of your `while` loop and can't be seen inside the `try` block.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Because that will 1) Keep your code nicely formatted, and 2) Tell you that you have a compile error when trying to use `values` outside the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to make your array visible to the writer is to declare it before setting it.

```
String line = null;
String[] values = null;
```

Then inside your while loop, you instantiate it.

```
values = line.split(",");
```

That way it is visible to the writer.

Comment: Even doing this, when I get to my for loop `for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {` I get an error saying that the variable `values` may not have been initialized

Comment: Then you can initialize the values array to null or an empty array(only if you know the size).

Answer (score 0):

To access your `values array` you have to declar it as a class member or at the top of the function:

```
public class Main {
   String[] values;
}
```

Comment: Or just above the while loop

Comment: I'm taking a stab in saying that `String[] values` would need to be initialized as `null`. If not, I *think* you'd get a compiler error because it'd think you'd be trying to iterate over an array that isn't instantiated.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Class variable objects are pre-initialized as null

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm pretty sure you'd get a compile-time error that `variable values may not have been initialized` due to the array being initialized in a different scope. Just dusted off NetBeans to check out if this were the case. However I will be more than happy to be wrong!

Comment: @DrewKennedy every member is initialized to null, or false and 0 for data primitives respectively.

Comment: This was my problem! I had to set it as `null` or I kept getting that exact error.

Comment: @javamatrix That's what I suspected. If an object is implicitly initialized as null, the JVM isn't smart enough to realize that you explicitly gave it a value in a different scope before reaching your loop. You will have to do it yourself. `String[] values = null;` is by no means a clean solution (using an ArrayList<T> would be better) but it is a working option.

Answer (score 0):

You would either need to add `values` in a list and iterate through the list, or you could also write as you read from the file.

As the scope of your values is in the while loop reading it, you may choose to write as you print it. That is:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] values = line.split(",");
    System.out.println("Your file has been evaluated, here are the contents:");
    for (String str : values) {
        System.out.println(str);
        fw.write(str + "\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply store an ArrayList and add each split line of the file to that list. Then you can iterate over this list later.

```
List<String[]> linesList = new ArrayList<>();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] values = line.split(",");
    linesList.add(values);
    System.out.println("Your file has been evaluated, here are the contents:");
    for (String str : values) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Then you can iterate over them later...

```
for (String[] values : linesList) {
    for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        String value = values[i];
        // Store your value here using your FileWriter, etc.
    }
}
```